# Bootstrap Form Helpers and yii1.*

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I need to add a choice of the country for one of the models on my site. I use yii1 and library yiibooster. I found a good plugin http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country/#jquery-plugins but he could not understand how the selected value to add to the database and display it after adding.

I originally made as follows, simply wrapped the box in the model...

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
    <?php echo $form->textFieldGroup($model,'country',array('widgetOptions'=>array('htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>255)))); ?>
</div>
```

But after submitting the form field "country" was displayed as "not set"

Then I added the necessary attributes directly in the "input"

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldGroup($model,'country',array('widgetOptions'=>array('htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span5 bfh-selectbox bfh-countries','maxlength'=>255,  'data-country'=>'US', 'data-flags'=>'true')))); ?>
```

but it didn't even display a list of countries.

How can I solve my problem? I saw that there is a Bootstrap Form Helpers for yii2, but to rewrite the project takes too much energy...

Comment: Show your resulted output.

Comment: @YatinMistry
after sending form i see "Country - Not set"

if look in database
"Country NULL"